# Trying to access a kubernetes API endpoint in my back end through my kubernetes angular app results int CORS browser error

Tags: angular, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Usually (without kubernetes, on my local machine), when I access the app it sends a get request to an API endpoint and it populates my angular app with information from there.

However, after I have uploaded the angular and the backend app to kubernetes and I access my angular app, the homepage loads but I get a 404 CORS errors from the API endpoint calls and no information is fetched so I just have a unpopulated homepage.

I have tried to use the information provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) but to no avail - meaning to start a chrome browser without security.

I also have added in my nginx file the information below but still doesn't work.
[image]

What information would you need to help you better understand the situation? I'm not sure what I should share.

Here is the angular app service yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: powerplant-angular-service
spec:
  selector:
      app: powerplant-angular
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

P.S. I have tested the kubernetes back-end API endpoint through postman and it works as expected, so the issue isn't from that application.

Answer (score 0):

Set the annotations in the config of Ingress as below.

```
 metadata:
   annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

checkout the [React w/ Kubernetes deployed API giving cors error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63944651/6910826)

hope this works

Comment: it's not a production app so I don't have an ingress, I only have a service and then I either port forward the app pod or the app service. I have updated the question and added the service.